# Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$. Prove that for each integer such as $n$, we have $(a b^{-1} a)^n = a b^n a^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I tried expanding $n$ parentheses such as $a b^{-1} a$ and then tried to replace the second $a$ with $a^2 a^{-1}$ but didn't know how to proceed further.

Also, is it possible to use commutativity here somehow?

Comment: There is a typo or some missing context. If $b$ is the identity element, this statement is $a^{2n} = e$ which is not always true.

Comment: Are you sure you got the expression right? I think it's supposed to be $(aba^{-1})^n$

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $$(aba^{-1})^n=ab^na^{-1}?$$

Comment: This is wrong even for $n=1$.

Comment: I edited the title of your question; now a proof is possible.

Comment: I checked the original question text, but it was exactly what I wrote in the first place. The equation was  $(a b^{-1} a)^n = a b^n a^{-1}$. Unless my professor has made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I do it *via* a simple inductive argument:

The trivial identity

$aba^{-1} = aba^{-1} \tag 1$

provides the $k = 1$ base case; for general $k$ we assume

$(aba^{-1})^k = ab^ka^{-1}; \tag 2$

then right multiplying by $aba^{-1}$:

$(aba^{-1})^{k + 1} = (ab^ka^{-1})aba^{-1} = (ab^k)(a^{-1}a)ba^{-1}$
$= (ab^k)eba^{-1} = ab^kba^{-1} = ab^{k + 1}a^{-1}, \tag 3$

where $e \in G$ is the identity element.  This completes the induction and hence we have

$(aba^{-1})^n = ab^na^{-1}, \tag 4$

for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

The inner adjacent $aa^{-1}$ terms cancel out, and this is fairly trivial:  $(aba^{-1})^n=aba^{-1}aba^{-1}\dots aba^{-1}=ab^na^{-1}$.